# where I made the mistake and how to fix it?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

````
#include <stdio.h>
float result(int x, int y);
float result1(int x, int y);


int main()
{
    int x,y;
    char z;
     printf("enter x:\n");
     scanf("%d",&x);
     printf("enter y:\n");
     scanf("%d",&y);

     printf("enter z:\n");
     scanf("%s",&z);

     

    if (z=='*')
     {printf("the result is %.2f",result(x,y));}

     else if (z=='/')
     {printf("the result is %.2f",result1(x,y));}

     else
     {printf("there is an error");}
return 0;
}

float result(int x, int y)
{
    float r=x*y;
    return r;
}

float result1(int x, int y)
{
    float r1=x/y;
    return r1;
}



```so this is my code. my out put is ---

enter x:
4
enter y:
5
enter z:
*
the result is 0.00
````

Question was -
take two integer number from user x and y and a character z. the result should be in float.
if z is * then it should be x*y
if z is / then it should be x/y
if z is none of the above then it will return 0
you need to use function .

so it was the question, I know it can be done by switch case but I wanted to try if else.

Comment: `%s` is not the correct format specifier for a single character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
scanf("%s",&z);
```

The format specifier `%s` is used to read *null-terminated **strings***. The variable `z` is a single character, it can only hold the empty string (which is only the null-terminator and nothing else).

Any other input will write somewhere in memory and lead to *undefined behavior*.

If you want to read a single character use the format `%c`. But be careful, the newline that the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key added from previous input will also be read with `%c`, and you need to ask `scanf` to skip and ignore it. This is done by adding a leading space to the format string.

So the call should be:

```
scanf(" %c",&z);
```